# Help understanding Harnack's inequality for compact subsets

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, connectedness

So I've been trying to understand the proof for the Harnack's inequality for compact subsets and been having a hard time grasping the arguments and reasoning the author is using. For reference I'm reading the proof from this document:

https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schmidt/lectures/PDE.pdf

I linked the document so anyone can see which version of the inequality I'm talking about and to see exactly which proof I'm looking into to. The proof and theorem are in page 36 and 37.

So I'm having a hard time understanding a couple of things, first why can we assume that $K$ is a connected set? He says you can take a bigger set to make it connected, but it doesn't seem that simple or obvious to me.
Second I don't understand the part where he supposedly proves that $S$ is connected by showing it both open and closed in $K$.
I think I got the right idea behind the chain of balls and connecting points through them, but my biggest.

Comment: It is good that you linked to the document you are working out of, but the document is 87 pages long, and the string "harnack" appears 17 times in that document.  Can you please include, at the very least, a more complete reference (i.e. the page number)?  Even better, please include the inequality in your question (as the linked document may not always exist).

Comment: Oh I forgot to add the page, really sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general fact about connected sets is the following: if $K$ is connected and $S \subseteq K$ is both open in $K$ and closed in $K$, then $S = K$.  You will find this in introductory books on point set topology or possibly undergraduate analysis texts.  It answers your second question.

As for your first question, the author of the notes you linked writes: "In view of the connectedness of $\Omega$ we can assume that $K$ is connected (for, if it is not, we can replace it with a larger compact subset which has this property)."  Here it really is important that $\Omega$ is connected and open.

Since $K \subseteq \Omega$ is compact and $\Omega$ is open, we can find finitely many closed balls $B_{1},B_{2},\dots,B_{N} \subseteq \Omega$ such that $K \subseteq B_{1} \cup \dots \cup B_{N}$.  Notice that $B_{1} \cup \dots \cup B_{N}$ is compact, but it may not be connected.

For each $i,j \in \{1,2,\dots,N\}$, let $\gamma_{ij} : [0,1] \to \Omega$ be a continuous function such that $\gamma_{ij}(0) \in B_{i}$ and $\gamma_{ij}(1) \in B_{j}$.  This is possible since $\Omega$ is a connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ --- such sets are always path connected.  (Look up the term "locally path connected.")  Using the notation $\{\gamma_{ij}\} = \{\gamma_{ij}(t) \, \mid \, t \in [0,T]\}$, define $K' \supseteq K$ by
\begin{equation*}
K' = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{N} B_{i} \cup \bigcup_{i,j = 1}^{N} \{\gamma_{ij}\}
\end{equation*}
Since I have added curves connecting any two of the balls, it should be intuitively clear that $K'$ is path connected --- and it is a relatively easy topology exercise to check that this is true.  ("Path connected" implies "connected," and it's easier to show something is path connected.)  At the same time, $K'$ is a finite union of compact sets so it is compact.

Comment: I still don't fully understand why the set $K/S$ is open in itself, he says that if $x \in K/S$ then it's contained in a certain ball $B_{i}$ of the covering such that that ball is contained in $K/S$. But I don't really see why that is valid